# Bind DNS slave for all zone

Tags: linux, dns, bind

We have `Bind9` running as a slave but i am wondering it doesn't have anywhere statment like `type slave` in named.conf but i can see its updating entries from master. We only add entries in master and add new zone but it automatically replicated to slave we never need to add or touch anything on slave. How does that slave configured?

`named.conf` i am seeing entries like this, does it enough to make it slave for all zone?

```
 allow-transfer { acl-nameservers; }; 
    allow-new-zones yes;

    server 192.168.100.10 { keys dns-xfer; };
        also-notify { 192.168.100.10; };
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably all your zones were added via command `rndc addzone`. This is allowed because of `allow-new-zones yes`

`man rndc`:

```
rndc addzone zone [class [view]] configuration
   Add a zone while the server is running. This command requires the
   allow-new-zones option to be set to yes. The configuration string
   specified on the command line is the zone configuration text that
   would ordinarily be placed in named.conf.

   The configuration is saved in a file called hash.nzf, where hash
   is a cryptographic hash generated from the name of the view. When
   named is restarted, the file will be loaded into the view
   configuration, so that zones that were added can persist after a
   restart.

   This sample addzone command would add the zone example.com to the 
   default view:

   $rndc addzone example.com '{ type master; file "example.com.db"; };'
```

So you may look if you find such *.nzf or *.db files in bind's working directory (e.g. /var/lib/named).